# type error >= not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

I have already written out my code but I keep getting an error message on `if personsAge >= 1`.

Here is the error:

> type error >= not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

This happens everytime I run my program. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
# Purpose
''' This program classifies a person to a certain group based on their age'''
#=================================================================================
# Initialize variables(used for processing data)
ageGroup =""; #specify data as empty string
personsAge =""; #specify data as float /real
#====================================================================================

# Input Statements
fullName = str(input("<Enter your full name>"));
personsAge = str(input("<Enter your age>"));

#==========================================================================
'''nested if statements to determine a person's age group.'''

# Using the Nested If eliminates the need to check all if statements
# Once the criteria has been met, control is transferred to the statement
# following the last if Statement. However, the IF/ELSE must be aligned in same column

if (personsAge <=1) and (personsAge >0):
    ageGroup = "Infant.";

elif (personsAge >=1) and (personsAge <=13):
    ageGroup = "Child.";

elif (personsAge >=13) and (personsAge <=20):
    ageGroup = "Teenager.";

elif (personsAge >=20):
    ageGroup = "Adult.";
#====================================================================================
#Output Statements
print();
print("My name is " + fullName);
print("My age is " + personsAge);

#=================================================================
# Print Age group
print(fullName + "is an " + ageGroup);
print("=" * 80);
#===============================================================================
#End program
```

Comment: You need to convert your input to an integer: `int(input("<Enter your full name>"))`.

Comment: You should have just googled this error. This gets asked at least once a day.

Comment: I'm sorry I am a beginner to coding

Comment: @Andrew Always just google the error. That should be your first step if you can't figure it out on your own.

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks. They broke the Android app. If I switch to a browser to find the dupe, I can't switch back to the app. I need to kill everything and reload it all. Very annoying.

Comment: Yup, that's one of the reasons I general don't do much StackOverflow-ing on my phone :P

Answer (score 4):

You are converting your input into a string instead of an integer.

**Use `int()` to convert your input to an integer:**

```
personsAge = int(input("<Enter your age>"));
```

Then you will be able to compare it to other integers.

Don’t forget to convert your `personsAge` integer to a string with `str()` everytime you concatenate `personsAge` with a string. Example:

```
print("My age is " + str(personsAge));
```

---

It is good practice to add error-handling where user input is not guaranteed to be of the required type. For example:

```
while True:
    try:
        personsAge = int(input("<Enter your age>"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please input an integer.')
        continue
```

Comment: I changed my input with persons age to an int, but now when I run it I'm getting type error: must be str not int

Comment: @Andrew You need to update your output statements. Now that `personsAge` is an integer, you should convert it to a string with `str()` everytime you try to concatenate it with a string. I edited my answer accordingly.